# Which file to adjust to allow .php files to display (not download)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having some trouble with .php files which seem to download when I open them in the browser.

I've googled around and have found this is because the server doesn't know how to parse the file, and that I need to add something to make this work.

I've read around and it seems I need to add something to a .htcaccess file, but I'm not sure where this is or where I should create it.

Below is a screenshot of the directories on my server if anyone can help me.

[image]

Comment: Have you got PHP installed on your server?

Comment: Hi this is a web server, and yes I've contacted the company and they say it has PHP installed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php
```

...this should already be in place in the master Apache file (or the appropriate .conf include - in some distributions, configuration directives may be parceled between several configuration files) if PHP is properly installed.

Comment: Hi, I've contacted the company and they have said PHP is properly installed. Is there anything else I can do to check?

Comment: If a file composed of just, say, `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and called 'tellme.php' gets downloaded instead of displaying the PHP info page, then so sorry, but PHP in my book is definitely NOT properly installed. What is happening is that the server says, "This is no proper PHP file". Why this happens, I do not know. There might be a permission/ownership problem (REALLY unlikely, you ought to get a 403/404 error), a site configuration problem (VERY likely), some PHP file format problem (again unlikely, you usually get a garbage page).

Comment: I'll double check with the provider. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to generate a htaccess file for this issue, if you installed a web server and php and configured them properly.

Comment: Hi, I've contacted the company and they have said PHP is properly installed. Is there anything else I can do to check?